# Dynamic ng-minlength / ng-maxlength

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add dynamic min/maxlength attributes using ng-minlength && ng-maxlength.

For example,

```
<input type="text" ng-minlength="myMin" ng-maxlength="myMax">
```

And in my controller...

```
$scope.myMin = 1;
$scope.myMax = 2;
```

However, this is not working. Ultimately, I want to be able to update these attributes and have the input reflect their values. Is this even possible?

Plunk example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KkUvFjSZkvFwqZVZAIiS?p=info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an ng model. Keep in mind that this will not limit the input. Only give you classes when the max and min values are valid/invalid.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="number" ng-minlength="myMin" ng-maxlength="myMax">

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myMin = 1;
  $scope.myMax = 5;
  $scope.number = 1;
});
```

If you just want to limit the input you can use regular html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="number" maxlength="{{myMax}}" >
```

I created a fork with both [examples](http://plnkr.co/edit/JGW6ROyOFsVwTjNkLXZo?p=preview).

Comment: Interestingly enough, in my own work I had a model assigned but it was not working as expected. When I changed to your second example's syntax, it worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)