# Add ng-maxlength to input after loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When user is entering the view. Angular is sending request to server and in response is name which consists of prefix and actual name (e.g.: PREFIX_NAME). 
In view I have 2 inputs (one for prefix and second for name). I want to set ng-maxlength attribute for name input which will be for example 25-prefix.length. I tried to set it like this:

```
ng-maxlength="{{maxLength}}"
```

but it have still first value (25), not value after substracting prefix length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic ng-minlength / ng-maxlength](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138274/dynamic-ng-minlength-ng-maxlength)

Comment: There is a working plnkr in the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: use `ng-maxlength="maxLength"`
`ng-maxlength` expects an js expression, not an interpolated value. If you open console, you should probably see an error saying that unexpected token '{'. Generally, you don't need double brackets when using `ng-*`.

Comment: When I do it without interpolation my input is invalid and have undefined model.

Comment: Have you initialize maxLength?@DonLeo

Comment: Yes, I do. At the start I have initialization: maxLength =25;
When I get response I set new maxLength substracting prefix length.

Comment: You should use `$scope.maxLength = 25`. Did you?@DonLeo

Comment: Yes, ofc. I just skip it in comment, sorry

Comment: I just found that, when I do it without interpolation and I inspect view there is ng-maxlength="maxLength" < name of variable, not value

Answer (score 0):

Your input should be:

```
<input ... ng-maxlength="maxLength"/>
```

In your controller, default set `maxLength`, and change it when recovering it from your API:

```
$scope.maxLength = 25;

$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/url' }).then(function(data) {
    $scope.maxLength = 25 - data;
});
```